# Check if a user is logged into my WordPress site which is on a different server

Tags: php, login

If I have a file example.php which loads WordPress and checks if a user is logged in to my WordPress site:

```
// Load WP
require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/wp-load.php' );

// Check if user is logged in and output a test message
if (is_user_logged_in()) {
    echo 'User is logged in';

} else {
    echo 'User is not logged in';
}
```

How can I run this file from another website which is on a different server to my WordPress site? As I want to check if the current user viewing website A is logged in to my WordPress website on website B.

It's possible to do it with an ajax request with jsonp, but is there a non JS solution to this?

It won't work with cURL because I don't think it's possible to check if the user is logged in using cURL.

PHP docs states that `include()` and `require()` can have external URLs if `allow_url_include` is set to 1 in `php.ini`, but I've read there are security concerns to this.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way for you is to share and check wordpress login cookie.

Check `wordpress_logged_in_[hash]` from your remote server